# How to save entry to struct

Tags: swift, struct, append, nsuserdefaults

Right now my code prints the struct that was entered, but it can only print the last individual entry entered. It can only store 1 entry. How can I store and print every entry in the struct.

```
@IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
    contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!, surname: b.text!  , phone: Int(c.text!)!))
    print(self.contacts.description)
}

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
}
```

Comment: Do you want to store multiple items in the contacts & print it ?

Comment: As was mentioned in your earlier question, do not use `Int` to store a phone number. A phone number is not a number in the math sense. It's a label. Use a `String`. And the code you posted here shows none of the improvements given to you in your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of person and append to it whenever someone press the button. Below is an example from swift playground.

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
}
var contacts = [Person]()

func press(name: String, surname: String, phone: Int) {
    contacts.append(Person(name: name, surname: surname, phone: phone))
    print(contacts.description)
}

press(name: "Aks", surname: "Homes", phone: 123)
press(name: "Harry", surname: "Potter", phone: 124)
press(name: "Ron", surname: "Weisly", phone: 345)
press(name: "Shan", surname: "Wate", phone: 456)
```